# How to add a label next to an arrow and respect the tilt in Ps?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I want to add text next to arrows and make the tilt of the text be equal to the tilt of the arrow.

If I do it manually with a free transform then, if I change the tilt of the arrow I have to manually change the tilt of the text too.

Does it exist a way to draw an arrow with a label next to it and have Photoshop arrange the tilt and the position of the label automatically, as I change the size and the tilt of the arrow?

Sketch of what I would like to have.
[image]

Comment: Photoshop isn't the greatest tool for this. A vector-based editor would be better... Illustrator, Inkscape, et al.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be complex - select the text layer and the arrow layer both at the same time and rotate them.

[image]

Have "Show transform controls" checked in the tool options bar for easy entering to the rotation, scaling and shifting as soon as the layers are selected in the layers panel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the same text line, use a special font for the arrow like [Wingding 3](https://www.wfonts.com/font/wingdings-3):

[image]

Make the transformation you need to the entire text box or line:

[image: textbox]

Comment: My question was ambiguous, sorry. I edited it